# How to install Oracle Linux using public oracle repositories?

Tags: oracle-linux

I've downloaded OL7.5 Boot ISO image and want to install the last version of Oracle Linux.

Which address could I use to do it?

[image]

NOTE: On the picture fields are inactive because of Network should be configured before.

Comment: In general people do network installs from sources on their own network, at LAN speed, and not over the internet- In other words : first  download  the installation sources and extract and copy their contents to a local web server or (NFS share) then use the address of that server -  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54695/html/ol7-install-network-server.html

Comment: We do not have storage space for this additional purpose and do not need a lot of OL installations. Only minimal install is preferable and install 'On the network' using Internet source seems  more appropriate for this purpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install specific version (for x86_64 platform):

> http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/5/base/x86_64/

Number 5 between `OL7/` and `/base` could be replaced by any available update number.

[image: OL7 repository site]

Installation of the last update of OL7 (for x86_64 platform) will be:

> http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/

[image: Latest network installation source]

After installation we have:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
```

Comment: Nice, but at next step in "Software Selection" left and right part are empty, cannot continue the installation. I tried "http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/UEKR6/x86_64/"

Comment: @sekrett Have you tried installation from something like https://yum.oracle.com/ISOS/OracleLinux/OL8/u3/x86_64/x86_64-boot-uek.iso
I haven't used OL or similar distros a long time. Later I could try to reproduce your situation.

Comment: No. I preferred to download full ISO, it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

As of today, this content has changed and the above is not correct. But using pointers from Gryu's answer above, I was able to find that the current URL for specifying at install time for base OS for current 8.3 is:

`public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/3/baseos/base/x86_64/`

Note the additional "baseos" inclusion. Also note that Oracle intentionally obfuscates these paths, as you cannot simply "navigate" to them via normal browser to confirm, so you need to poke around to find the appropriate path if it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Installing OL 8.4 from UEK network iso (`x86_64-boot-uek_8.4.iso`, 732MB)

[image]

**URLs:**

BaseOS: https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/x86_64/

AppStream: https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/appstream/x86_64/

UEK: https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/UEKR6/x86_64/

**You can find the URLs yourself here:**

https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-8.html